# Need to sort this SQL result by RAND

Tags: php, sql

I have the following sql and need to sort the results in random order. I tried adding ORDER BY RAND() but was unsuccessful. I may be missing the syntax on it.

```
$items = Goods_Model_Good::findByCop(array(
       'where' => new JO_Db_Expr(
             'good.id IN (SELECT id
                            FROM good
                            WHERE copId LIKE ' . Helper_Db::quote($cop['copId']) .
     ')')));
```

Comment: So... add an `ORDER BY RAND()` to your `SELECT` statement?

Comment: @ceejayoz That is what I tried but I am pretty new to the selects and don't seem to be getting the syntax right. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you're using some sort of weird home-grown database class, so it's hard to help you further.

Comment: Tx @ceejayoz.  I didn't write this but in short, this is what it does:  findbyCop is the model function.  The array grabs all the id's in the 'good' table where the copId column matches the copId column in the 'cop' table.  Clear as mud?

Comment: Clear as mud.  The class obfuscates things.  If you show us the resulting SQL, we can help you there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP you get an array shuffled with shuffle:

```
shuffle($items);
```

Comment: is that extra 1 supposed to be there? Also, the OP is looking for a query solution, not array.

Comment: @Evan Carslake: No, the 1 is  a typo of course. The OP gets the data with SQL and wants it shuffled. You can shuffle in PHP. Why not? In SQL it depends very much on the DBMS how to shuffle data, so a pure SQL solution would make this less portable.

Comment: Thank you @ThorstenKettner. Your solution worked perfectly for my needs.

Comment: You know, I'm always the guy saying "keep it to the dbms side" but in this case I think you're right. It's also less likely that you screw up the optimizer with a weird order by clause if you keep it at the application side. Also, I think php 7 improved the performance aspect of some arrays functions...

Comment: @Sebas definitely makes sense, the database already has its own chores. One less chore is all around better.